# « Arrogant », « moqueur » ou « méprisant »?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, définition

Mon patron me dit :

Salut Priscilla, est-ce que tu pourrais aller nettoyer l’entrée du magasin avec un balai. Un balai, Priscilla, tu sais c’est quoi un balai, hein, tout en faisant un mouvement de bras rappelant celui qu’on fait pour balayer.

Et de me dire intérieurement :

Non mais il l’a vraiment pris avec moi sur un ton

…arrogant.

…moqueur.

…méprisant.

Ou autre ?

Les reformulations sont les bienvenues.

Edit :

D’autres adjectifs qui me viennent en tête:

…condescendant.

…de supériorité/supérieur.

Dans le contexte, l’attitude du patron dénote-t-il de l’arrogance ou de la moquerie, voire les deux? J’ai de la peine à distinguer l’une de l’autre.

Autre exemple:

Une cliente d’une apparence soignée et bien habillée du magasin en question réussit à sortir avec un objet volé, mais le patron parvient à la prendre sur le fait et à l’intercepter à l’extérieur. À son retour, le patron nous compte, à d’autres collègues du service à la clientèle et à moi, le fâcheux incident et moi, étant surprise de la situation, je lui dis: cette cliente-là a vraiment volé un article!? Et lui de me répondre: ben quin, qu’est-ce que t’en penses, d’un air sec et en me montrant l’article volé. Ici, devrait-on assimiler l’attitude du patron à de l’arrogance ou à de la moquerie?

Comment: C'est plutôt un patron qui prend sa subordonnée pour une cruche, une nunuche, une blonde … à qui il fait tout expliquer avec des exemples ou des preuves pour qu'elle comprenne ce qu'il dit …

Comment: @Personne On pourrait alors dire que le patron manifeste du mépris et qu’il a adopté un ton méprisant?

Comment: D’un ton humiliant, dégradant, avilissant?

Comment: Cela dépend de l'intonation, la condescendance teintée d'ironie devrait suffire pour le balai. Si vraiment la personne n'est pas à sa place, elle est virée. Si elle fait bien son travail, mais qu'elle ne comprend pas les codes sociaux et les situations et surtout qu'elle ne croit pas ce que son patron lui dit, la réponse de ce dernier au sujet du sac est plutôt mesurée… quand on ne comprend pas une situation, mieux vaut se mettre silencieusement en retrait et attendre que la réponse à la question que l'on se pose apparaisse d'elle-même…

Comment: C'est le patron qui est humilié quand on doute de son témoignage, surtout quand il a la preuve de ses dires entre les mains et que c'est une subordonnée qui l'interpelle !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le ton du patron me paraît **infantilisant**, et pourrait s'inscrire plus largement dans une attitude **paternaliste**.

J'y sens du **mépris**, une pointe d'**arrogance** et on peut y voir [du sarcasme (comme l'évoque jlliagre)](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51462/8179)

L'arrogance n'est pas nécessairement accompagnée de moqueries. Je le vois comme un comportement hautain, de quelqu'un qui se sentirait supérieur, qui mépriserait des personnes de son entourage.

Les moqueries ne sont pas toujours dues à de l'arrogance. Elles peuvent venir de taquineries, de situation embarassantes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Le patron est ***sarcastique***, mélangeant ironie et railleries offensantes.

Il ***brocarde*** son employée, il se ***fout de sa gueule***.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasme

Answer (score 0):

Personnellement, je penserais moquerie. L’arrogance, c’est plutôt se mettre au-dessus des autres, en ce qui concerne l’argent, l’intelligence, la position, etc.
Le patron vous ridiculise davantage au lieu d'agir comme supérieur.

Juste mon avis